# Is it possible to upload image in local storage in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap

Is it possible to upload image in local storage in phonegap 7.1.1? I have used.

[PhoneGap: Uploading Pictures To Local Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730467/phonegap-uploading-pictures-to-local-folder)

Thanks,